# Nested Codeigniter apps not working in NGINX

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

We've setup 2 CodeIgniter apps which has its own complete code bases on its own directories as in this example. Plus we also have wordpress blog on the same public_html directory.

```
public_html/HOME_APP
public_html/admin_tool/ADMIN_TOOL_CODES
public_html/blog/WORDPRESS_CODES
```

`HOME_APP` codes (CodeIgniter) and our `WORDPRESS` works fine. But the `admin_tool` (CodeIgniter) doesn't work. We can access only the `http://example.com/admin_tool/index.php` but not any inside controller pages. When accessing its show `404` error page. And it looks like the routes are handled via `APP1`

The nginx rules are as follows. Appreciate if anyone can help us to fix the issue with `admin_tool`

```
 server{
        listen   80;
        root /home/ubuntu/websites/example.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name example.com;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/websites/example.com/logs/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/websites/example.com/logs/error.log error;

        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                        expires max;
                        log_not_found off;
                }

         location / {          
            index index.php;
            # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
                }



        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

         }

    location ^~/admin_tool/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/websites/example.com/public_html/admin_tool;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
}


}
server {
  listen   443 ssl;
  server_name  example.com *.example.com;
  return      301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick for all of your installations:

```
# We define the index directory at the outermost level and therefore
# only once for all servers. Also note that we use the PHP file first
# because all main directories are handled by PHP scripts and this will
# give us best performance.
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server {
  access_log  /home/ubuntu/websites/example.com/logs/access.log;
  error_log   /home/ubuntu/websites/example.com/logs/error.log error;
  # 80 is default!
  #listen      80;
  root        /home/ubuntu/websites/example.com/public_html;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {

    # Don't allow access to the logs directory.
    location ~* ^/logs {
      return 404;
    }

    # Don't allow access to PHP files.
    location ~* \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }

    # Handle static files.
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
      expires       max;
      log_not_found off;
    }

    # Directly return if the requested URI is a real file.
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php =404;

  }

  # Codeigniter and WordPress will always handle everything with their
  # index.php script, therefore we only need to catch that case.
  location = /index.php {
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

}

server {
  listen      443 ssl;
  server_name example.com *.example.com;
  return      301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I am using codeigniter in subfolder(dashboard).
All non-wordpress requests are not being entertained but remain on wordpress main page. 
I fixed my issue by following lines in my configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/{my-site-name}

```
location /dashboard {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /dashboard/index.php;
}

location /index.php {
   fastcgi_pass  unix:/usr/sbin/php5-fpm;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
 }
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks you Anuruth Sharma for pointing out my mistake now it is an answer.